# Unexpected behaviour in a for loop

Tags: c++

This compiles and runs, but produces garbage values for "a". Why doesn't "a" increment like "b"? Why is it producing garbage?

```
for(a,b=0; a,b != 55; a,b++)
{
    //outputs garbage
    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
    //outputs expected results 
    std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: you need to study c++ syntax -- in particular the comma operator doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Of course it works! However, it may work in a way different from what you expected. How do you expect the program to work?

Comment: works for me, what output are you expecting?

Comment: @DaveB To be pedantic, it doesn't work for you since as written it contains undefined behavior.  the `a` variable is uninitialized.

Comment: Because it is equivalent to `for(b=0; b != 55; b++)`.

Comment: @DaleWilson good point, I should have said I get the output I expected.

Comment: Seems the OP needs to define "doesn't work" -- not really clear what is expected here; are they expecting the `a` variable to magically define itself? -- to magically increment itself? -- (Because as defined, the program says that `a` outputs garbage, and that's exactly what it does, and it's exactly what you would expect it to do -- so, the OP will need to define their expected behavior a little better.)

Comment: I expected to see both variables to be incremented.

Comment: I changed it to be more specific.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 Respectively, If I understood it, I wouldn't need to have asked it, the previous comments covered what needed to be asked and to me it seems like that was a bit much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comma operator says execute the expression on the left then execute the expression on the right:

```
  a, b=0
```

first executes `a` which does nothing, then it executes `b=0` which assigns zero to b.

Why does the comma operator exist?  The comma operator can be useful when the expressions have side effects.

It also serves a sequence point which tell the compiler "everything on the left must be complete before anything on the right happens.  This constrains the optimizations allowed by the compiler, so for example a += 1, b = a + c[a] will always add one to a before using it as an index.  Something like b = ++a + c[a] is undefined because the compiler can increment a before or after it uses it as an index.